# Deleting a node in the center of a single linked list. What happens to the node?

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question regarding the deletion of a node in the center of a linked list given that you only have access to that node. I've taken a look at the solution and while I understand what is happening, I am confused as to what actually happens to the node. For instance, if I have the nodes with values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in my linked list, why am I left with 1, 2, 4, 5 instead of 1, 2, 4, 4, 5?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
SinglyList.prototype.deleteMiddle = function(value) {
    var current = this.head;
    while (current.value !== value) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (current.next) {
        current.value = current.next.value;
        current.next = current.next.next;
    } else {
        current = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have linked list with nodes 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, from which node 3 is removed. The removal of node 3 is actually a redirecting of some links. In this case, node 2 will not link to node 3 as its *next* node anymore, but it will link to node 4 as its *next* node instead. In case of a doubly linked list, this is also true the other way around, e.g. node 4 will link back to node 2 instead of node 3.

So, node 3 will not actually be removed physically, but any references to node 3 will be removed, which means logically it does not exist anymore. At some point in time, a garbage collector will remove node 3 physically because there are no more references pointing to that node.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the prompt reply. I've updated my original post with my function. I understand that if the function stopped iterating at Node 2, then I would be able to set Node 2's next to Node 4. However, my function stops on the node that is being deleted (i.e Node 3) and then sets Node 3's .value and .next to Node 4's.

Comment: Then your conditions should be a bit different. You should check if `current.next.value` is equal to your `value` given as input to the function. If that is the case, let the current node point to the node two steps away, like this: `current.next = current.next.next`.

Comment: Hey Froodoo, that makes sense as the loop will stop iterating when current.next.value is equal to 3 (thus leaving current at Node 2) but now I'm even more curious as to what is happening as the method listed above works as intended.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that the algorithm specifically states that you only have access to the node in the center that is to be deleted. Thus, there would no traversing so there should be no reference to Node 2.

Comment: In your method, the following happens. When node 3 (with value 3) is reached, this node gets the same value as the next node (`current.next`), which is 4. So now we have this: `1 - 2 - 4 - 4 - 5`. Then, the current node's *next*  pointer is redirected to `current.next.next`, which is node 5 (with value 5). So from node 3 (which has now value 4), we're redirect to node 5 (with value 5). So what you actually do is skipping the fourth node, but that does not matter because the third node has now the same value as the fourth node. So in the end we still have 1 - 2 - 4 - 5.

Comment: Bingo, I kind of understand it now. So essentially the list becomes 1, 2, 4, 4, 5. Does it matter that the 2nd 4 is just sitting there idle? Also, does Node 2's next (which previously pointed to Node 3) automatically update to Node 4 since objects are stored in memory by reference and not be value? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The object node 2 (with value 2) will still point to the object node 3 (but this node has now value 4). In that respect this is not the cleanest way of removing a node from a linked list, because node objects could become messed up after a lot of value changes (a node *X* does not necessarily also have value *X*, but could have a completely different value *Y*). The second 4 (e.g. object node 4 with value 4) does not have another node anymore which points to him (e.g. all references to object node 4 are gone).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104714/discussion-between-froodooo-and-stockdc2), if needed.

Comment: Hey Froodoo, messaged you in chat but just in case, to reiterate what you said, Node 2 will still point to the 3rd node (which now is technically not Node 3 since the value is 4 although it is the 3rd node) in the sequence and the 2nd Node 4 is now sitting in limbo since the 1st Node 4 references Node 5, thus skipping over it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need another variable for the last node.

If not at the start, then combine the previous next pointer to the actual next pointer:

```
lastNode.next = node.next;
```

Working model:

```js
function Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = undefined;
}

function setValues(a) {
    var n = new Node(a.shift());
    if (a.length) {
        n.next = setValues(a);
    }
    return n;
}

function deleteNode(list, value) {
    var node = list,
        lastNode;
    while (node.value !== value) {     // find value
        lastNode = node;
        node = node.next;
    }
    if (lastNode) {                    // inside the list
        lastNode.next = node.next;
    } else {                           // at the start
        list.value = node.next.value;
        list.next = node.next.next;
    }
}

var list1 = setValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
deleteNode(list1, 3);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Hey Nina, thanks so much for the reply. Your functions are extremely interesting and very cool since you're using recursion to set up your list. To summarize, you have 2 pointers running simultaneously, one of which keeps track of the current node and the other which keeps track of the previous to that node correct? However, I just realized that the algorithm states that you only have access to the node being deleted; traversing through the list is not an option.

Comment: right. how do you like to get the node and the predecessor if you do not traversin through all nodes? a solution coud be a double linked list with predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this relates to JavaScript but you can think of a Linked List as a series of nodes:

`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`

Each node has a pointer to the next node. When you remove 3, the pointer from on 2 to 3 is updated to point to what 3 pointed to (4). So you end up with:

`1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5`

If you are asking how do you delete it if you can't go backwards to see that 2 is pointing to 3, well think about how you traverse a linked list -- there is only one way to go. So an algorithm to remove a node is going to have to keep a pointer to the prior, current and next node. That way, when the current node is remove (3), it can look at the prior (2) and the next (4). Of course 3 already has a reference to 4 so the next pointer isn't needed.

Comment: Hey Cymen, thanks so much for the prompt reply. The confusing part is that my function iterates until it reaches the node that is to be deleted (i.e Node 3). Once it gets there, it sets Node 3's .value and .next to Node 4's properties. Like you mentioned, you can't go backwards and when the list was traversed, Node 2's next was Node 3. Since Node 2 is essentially out of the picture now, I'm still not understanding how Node 2 knows to jump to Node 4.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one linked list implementation out there. But if we're talking abstract: if you remove one element in a linked list, it becomes two linked lists. one ending before the removed element, the second one beginning after the removed element.

What happens to the node ist what you actually mean by "deleting". There is no "emtpy" space in the linked list where the removed node once was. It was removed, as requested. Depending on the implementation of the remove operation the lose ends of the two resulting lists can be combined, to form a (one!) new linked list, with 1,2,4,5. Or they are not, then you end up with described 2 lists. The end of list 1 points to nil / null / somwhere, the reference to the beginning of the other list is lost, unless you saved it somewhere.

So you end up with either `1->2->4->5` or `1->2->` + `4->5`

Comment: I missed the "javascript"-tag from your question. My answer is more generally talking about the abstract data type and implementations. I don't the JS-flavor actually...

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the reply and the explanation about lists not having empty spaces.